# Assignment to a variable is changing all other references to that variable's previous value

Tags: python, io

I'm writing a program that does some creative redirecting of output streams. I have a storage dictionary of what streams I've redirected, tied to the ID of the thread that redirected them (I have one each for `stdout` and `stderr` - the latter is below, `_stderr_redirects`). I'll go into detail later about *how* my redirection works, but suffice it to say each key in the dict corresponds to a value representing a list of streams. Whatever's last in that list is the one to which to output.

To avoid code reuse, I've tried to write one method to add to this dict (`_push_stream()`), which can be called with a string designating the stream name. This is used to index into `_stream_redirects`, which returns the dict `_stderr_redirects`.

```
_stderr_redirects = {}
...
_stream_redirects = {"stderr":_stderr_redirects, ...}

def _push_stream(new_dest, stream_name):
    current_thread_id = threading.current_thread().ident
    if current_thread_id in _stream_redirects[stream_name]:
        _stream_redirects[stream_name][current_thread_id].append(new_dest)
    else:
        _stream_redirects[stream_name][current_thread_id] = [new_dest]  # DEBUG 1
    pass                                                                # DEBUG 2
```

I call this method as follows:

```
with open("turn_off_stderr.txt", "r") as infile:
    _push_stream(infile, "stderr")
```

I have like three different references throughout my code to a particular instance of my custom stream: At the point `DEBUG 1`, it is pointed to by the variables `sys.stderr`, `sys.__stderr__`, and a module-level variable `_quiet_stderr`.

As soon as I step to the point `DEBUG 2`, however, all three of those references change to whatever `new_dest` was (in this example, a file descriptor to a file `turn_off_stderr.txt`). This happens reliably and consistently, and I have screenshots to prove it.

- [Here's what the PyCharm Debugger looks like before executing line `DEBUG 1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHtaD.png)
- [Here's what the PyCharm Debugger looks like one line later, before executing line `DEBUG 2`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZf7E.png)

**Why is this happening, and how can I fix this behavior while adhering to good code reuse standards?**

---

I've done a lot of tinkering with this, and after several hours of attempted debugging, I've found one clear toggle that seems to have a causal link to this behavior. Here's the class with which I'm replacing my streams (comments inlined/indented for clarity):

```
_orig_sys_dests = {
    "stderr": sys.stderr,
    ...
}

class QuietIOWrapper(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        super().__init__(_orig_sys_dests[name].buffer)

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item in ["_name", "__setattr__"]:                                       # retrieve our own instance variables, using super() to avoid recursion error
            return super().__getattribute__(item)
        current_thread_id = threading.current_thread().ident                       # get the current thread's ID and the current self name reference
        stream_name = self._name
        try:                                                                       # get the current thread's stream, or if not set then the default stream
            # THE FOLLOWING LINE IS THE PROBLEMATIC ONE
            target_stream = _stream_redirects[stream_name][current_thread_id][-1]
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            target_stream = _orig_sys_dests[stream_name]
        if target_stream == self:
            target_stream = _orig_sys_dests[stream_name]                           # avoid infinite recursion error by defaulting to user-intended stream if target is self
        return target_stream.__getattribute__(item)                                # forward request for attribute to the target stream


    def write(self, s):
        self.write(s)                                                              # Dummy method to redirect to default stream, if __getattribute__() would be bypassed

sys.stdout = QuietIOWrapper("stdout")
sys.stderr = QuietIOWrapper("stderr")
sys.__stdout__ = sys.stdout
sys.__stderr__ = sys.stderr
```

The line right after my comment `# THE FOLLOWING LINE IS PROBLEMATIC` is the toggle that determines whether this behavior does or doesn't happen. Its current form triggers the issue. The following line also does, just by existing:

```
target_stream = _stderr_redirects[current_thread_id][-1]
```

If this line is omitted (i.e. if `_stderr_redirects` is not referred to here, even by proxy), the error I've described above does not happen.

I tried putting a breakpoint on that line, and it did not get hit even once before the above error occurred (which I caught on a different breakpoint).

The mere existence of that line must be causing the error, but I have absolutely no idea why, or how I can stop it from happening. This error is not compatible with my current understanding of python as a language.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What I've given so far is as close to a MVE as I can get - all the code in my file that isn't listed here consists of placeholder variables that don't do anything yet, and methods that chain-call each other to get to these methods (they literally don't do anything besides that). If my error is not reproducible with this code, then that indicates there's a problem with my environment - finding what that problem is would qualify as a valid answer to this question in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the cause of your issue, but `except KeyError or IndexError:` doesn't do what you want. You should use `except (KeyError, IndexError):`.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're overwriting the `sys.__whatever__` streams? Those are specifically intended to not be changed, so that if there's an error and the existing `sys.stderr` is broken, it can still output something. Your code is likely buggy (in some way), but you can't see the exceptions because you've overwritten the stream that it would be printed on, and the fallback stream.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for point that out. Unfortunately, fixing it didn't fix the problem. I also tried not changing `sys.__stderr__`, and the same behavior still happened but only for `sys.stderr`, when I moved from the first breakpoint to the next line. My code *is* likely buggy, but the issue here definitely isn't that I can't see exceptions - I'm looking at this in a line-by-line debugger and can see exactly what variables change and how from line to line. The lack of output was what clued me in to there being a problem in the first place, which is why I started debugging.